# Translate an add-in in Hebrew

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, hebrew

I'm trying to translate my Outlook add-in in hebrew but I'm facing a problem: how to write the text from right to left only for this language? I want to translate the add-in description in the XML manifest file and in the JS source code (my add-in creates an email with a pre-defined template translated in the user's language).

Does anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this article help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization

Comment: In fact I used this article to localize my add-in but it doesn't explain how to configure special behaviors due to specific regions/languages.

Comment: Right-to-left behavior is usually built into the font, so the programmer doesn't have to do anything. Have you tested the add-in in Hebrew? If so, does anything go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run your add-in localized in a hebrew-enabled host application? How does it look like?

Comment: I installed the Hebrew language pack and configured Outlook in Hebrew. I then ran the add-in and the text is still from left to right.

Comment: What text are you referring to? Is this the text for the email that the add-in creates?

Answer (score 0):

can you paste here a snippet of the translated text? I think that the text itself is OK. A small screen shot should also help.

Maybe only the text alignment is bad. Text direction and alignment is not the same. Hint: to see text direction, look for the "." at the end of the sentences, are they on the left? RTL direction. Right (as on this text)? LTR.